# Cable required for pulling 3 phase power outdoors

Tags: electrical, outdoor

Might be stupid questions but what kind of cable I for pulling 3 phase power outdoors around 10 meters outside. Frost is not an issue but even if I pull the cable within a pipe there is a good chance of moisture over its life.

Comment: According to code underground conduit is considered to be full of water all the time. The wire requirements reflect that.

Comment: Yeah, definitely bury it, preferably in conduit, not like what they did at Fukushima when they just draped across the ground to save units 2 and 3, and they took physical damage and put em put of business.

Comment: Cool cable sorted. Turns out that only type of 3 phase 5 cable sold in my local hardware store was the on mentioned for outdoor usage because the common use cases here are household EV charging and 400V patio heaters. People pull outdoor cable to induction hubs as well just in case.

Comment: Also I was advised not only to burry cable (in fact violation of building code here) but to pull it using pipe sleeve so physical damage ist threatening the cable ether.

Answer (score 1):

If you run conduit ("pipe" intended for electrical wire protection) you generally use individual wires, NOT cable (several wires bundled in an outer jacket) - they pull easier than a cable, and the conduit is all the outer jacket required, and a better one than a cable has.

Your local standards are undoubtedly in line with most others worldwide in considering any exterior conduit to be full of water all the time. As such, wiring for use in such conduit is "wet-rated" and works perfectly well in water. Your local electrical supplier will have such wire.

If the conduit is to be buried, there are likely standards for minimum burial depth (which may vary with what type of conduit it is) and how it is to be marked. If it is above ground, but below ~2.5m height there are likely standards for what type of conduit is considered sturdy enough for use exposed to damage. I am familiar with those standards in my local area but not in the Netherlands (location per your other question) - however, I'm tolerably certain that such standards will exist locally.

Answer (score 0):

You would need wire for a wet location so a common type, at least here in the USA, would be THHW or THWN. You might have to check with your suppliers for equivalent types.